# Image path is broken after updating site from Craft version 3 to 4

Tags: assets, craft4, aws, filesystem

I am currently in the process of upgrading my site from 3 to 4. My craft CMS version is 4.4.16.1
None of my images are loading in the site after performing update. Our images are stored in AWS.
Upon closer inspection, sub folder is missing from the asset URL. I have also noticed that column named "settings" is missing from the "craft_volumes" table.
The "settings" column contains the info about the sub folder of our assets.
I am not sure how to correctly load the image path after updating to Craft 4.
Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: Hey Sajjan - feel free to add this comment as an answer and then approve it as the selected answer. This is absolutely allowed and encouraged, and takes this out of the unanswered questions pool. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

In case, anyone is facing the same issue, I finally figured it out. Craft 4 has introduced Filesystems which basically takes all the file storage settings out of Volumes. When I ran the craft migration, it deleted all our AWS settings from Volumes but didn't create respective Filesystems due to which our images failed to load. I had to manually create all the Filesystems and link it to respective Volumes in order to fix the issue.

Comment: Feel free to mark your own answer as "The Answer", it's allowed and encouraged to remove the question from the unanswered queue. Cheers!